# Filter number in a DataView using RowFilter in C#4.0

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I'm trying to filter my DataView DataSet using RowFilter.

I would like to perform a like statement on an Integer column

So something like this:

```
myDataView.RowFilter ="ID LIKE %1%";
```

This works fine for string columns but I receive an error when trying this will integers. 
I receive the follow error: Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.Int32.

Anyway of doing a LIKE statement on numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It worked with me:

```
"Convert(DataGridColumnName, 'System.String') LIKE '%" & txtBox.Text & "%' "
```

Answer (score 2):

You must convert using `cast`.

```
"Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE  %1%"
```

Comment: That doesn't work I receive the following error now: The expression contains undefined function call CAST().

Comment: Sorry, but it's a no. I now get: Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Mod' operator

Comment: For Mod error wrap quotes around it.  ie Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE  '%1%'

Answer (score 0):

This gets the specific item requested. It works on one item exactly

```
"Convert(DataGridColumnName, 'System.String') LIKE '%" & txtBox.Text & "%' "
```

Example 1:

```
 DV.RowFilter = "Convert( TicketNo , 'System.String') LIKE  '%" + txtTicketNo.Text + "%'
```

This only receive the exact ticket number if you want to retreive items like that start with it receives all items that start with

Example 2:

```
DV.RowFilter = "Convert( TicketNo , 'System.String') LIKE  '" + txtTicketNo.Text + "%' ";
```

In Theory the first Example should be looking in the whole string and searching for matches.
The one that I have done does not do that maybe I had missed something,